# radio button value pass undefined in parent page

Tags: javascript, php, radio-button

i am using tow pagge one is parent page and other is child window page for pass the radio button value from  child window page to parent page but i have getting error  undefined  in parent page text fields...

**parent page**

```
<form method="post" action="" name="f1">
<table border=0 width=550>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Your Name
            <input id="OPRID" name="OPRID" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST

         ['OPRID']) ? $_POST['OPRID'] : ""); ?>" /> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" name="My Window Name" title=" My title here "  

   onClick="window.open  
    ('popwindow.php','Ratting','width=650,height=550,0,status=0,scrollbars=1');" />
                Click here to open the child window
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

**child window page** 

<html>
 <head>

 <script langauge="javascript">
  function post_value(){
  opener.document.f1.OPRID.value = document.frm.OPRID.value;
  self.close();
    }
   </script>
   <form name="frm" method="post" action=''>
  <tr>  
   <td><div align="center">
  <input type="radio" name="OPRID" id="radio" value="<?php echo $objResult ["OPRID"];? 
   >" /></div></td>  
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["OPRID"];?></td>
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["OPRDEFNDESC"];?></td>
   </tr>
    <?  
    }  
   ?>  
    </table>  
  <br />

  <tr> 
  <td><div align="center"> <input type="button" value='Submit' onclick="post_value();"> </div>
   </td>
    </tr> 
    </form>
 but in text fields i have getting undefined error.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be done with using HTML5 sessionStorage feature.

Check this link: http://playground.html5rocks.com/#sessionstorage

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
window.opener.document.f1.OPRID.value = document.frm.OPRID.value;
```

instead of this

```
opener.document.f1.OPRID.value = document.frm.OPRID.value;
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Why would this help? `opener` doesn't seem to be shadowed by anything in `post_value`

Comment: while passing value from child to parent it is best way to use common object that is window. window object is accessible by child as well as parent and it contains opener for that particular child.